# IPv6 usage statistics

Tags: statistics, ip-address, ipv6

does anybody know current situation about IPv6 penetration in the public Internet?

I would like to know how IPv6 addresses are currently used, because of development of the feature which relies on user host IP addresses. The question is, if it is **worth while to consider also IPv6 addresses**.

I've found some statistics from 2008, but I guess that nowadays situation is different.

Thanks

Comment: The situation isn't different by a huge amount. Anyone who might actually have good data on the situation now either isn't telling or will want to charge you much money for the information.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246930/since-ipv6-is-going-to-replace-ipv4-should-i-develop-my-new-application-to-suppor

Comment: Thanks, I've not found the question before. Interesting discussion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://labs.ripe.net/content/ipv6-measurement-compilation) has the results of various studies into IPv6 usage.  It is a bit hard to interpret the numbers, and many of them are rather dated (e.g. 2009), but the numbers are still pretty low both in terms of numbers of end-users with working IPv6 connectivity and websites that are accessible via IPv6.

However, it is clear that we are going to run out of unallocated IPv4 addresses pretty soon.  For example, Geoff Huston's "[IPv4 Report](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/index.html)" page predicts exhaustion of Regional Internet Registries (RIRs) pools of unallocated IPv4 addresses by March 2012.  **So things are going to have to change.**

And anyone who does not consider IPv6 support in any new application / webapp is being very short-sighted.

Comment: Good summary - it's something like what I was finding. Thanks!

Comment: The song of "IPv4 is running out of address space" is an old one and amazingly enough, everything still runs on IPv4. That is not to say that any modern hardware or software should ignore IPv6 - just that I've heard this now about milion times by now.

Comment: @RolandTepp - Have tried getting a large block of IP addresses recently?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is worthwhile to consider. But that's a pretty vague answer to a vague question.